# How do I fix blurry text in my HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am a total *n00b* with `HTML5` and am working with the `canvas` to render shapes, colors, and text. In my app, I have a *view adapter* that creates a canvas dynamically, and fills it with content. This works really nicely, except that my text is rendered very fuzzy/blurry/stretched. I have seen a lot of other posts on why defining the *width* and *height* in `CSS` will cause this issue, but I define it all in `javascript`.

The relevant code (view [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65maD/)):

```js
var width  = 500;//FIXME:size.w;
var height = 500;//FIXME:size.h;
    
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
//canvas.className="singleUserCanvas";
canvas.width=width;
canvas.height=height;
canvas.border = "3px solid #999999";
canvas.bgcolor = "#999999";
canvas.margin = "(0, 2%, 0, 2%)";
    
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

//////////////////
////  SHAPES  ////
//////////////////
    
var left = 0;

//draw zone 1 rect
context.fillStyle = "#8bacbe";
context.fillRect(0, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width*1.5/8.5, canvas.height*1/6);

left = left + canvas.width*1.5/8.5;

//draw zone 2 rect
context.fillStyle = "#ffe381";
context.fillRect(left+1, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width*2.75/8.5, canvas.height*1/6);

left = left + canvas.width*2.75/8.5 + 1;

//draw zone 3 rect
context.fillStyle = "#fbbd36";
context.fillRect(left+1, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width*1.25/8.5, canvas.height*1/6);

left = left + canvas.width*1.25/8.5;

//draw target zone rect
context.fillStyle = "#004880";
context.fillRect(left+1, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width*0.25/8.5, canvas.height*1/6);

left = left + canvas.width*0.25/8.5;
    
//draw zone 4 rect
context.fillStyle = "#f8961d";
context.fillRect(left+1, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width*1.25/8.5, canvas.height*1/6);

left = left + canvas.width*1.25/8.5 + 1;

//draw zone 5 rect
context.fillStyle = "#8a1002";
context.fillRect(left+1, (canvas.height*5/6)+1, canvas.width-left, canvas.height*1/6);

////////////////
////  TEXT  ////
////////////////

//user name
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.font = "bold 18px sans-serif";
context.textAlign = 'right';
context.fillText("User Name", canvas.width, canvas.height*.05);

//AT:
context.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
context.fillText("AT: 140", canvas.width, canvas.height*.1);

//AB:
context.fillText("AB: 94", canvas.width, canvas.height*.15);
       
//this part is done after the callback from the view adapter, but is relevant here to add the view back into the layout.
var parent = document.getElementById("layout-content");
parent.appendChild(canvas);
```

```html
<div id="layout-content"></div>
```

The results I am seeing (in *Safari*) are much more skewed than shown in the Fiddle:

**Mine**

[image: Rendered output in Safari]

**Fiddle**

[image: Rendered output on JSFiddle]

What am I doing incorrectly? Do I need a separate canvas for each text element? Is it the font? Am I required to first define the canvas in the HTML5 layout? Is there a typo? I am lost.

Comment: Seems like you're not calling `clearRect`.

Comment: This polyfill fixes most basic canvas operations with HiDPI browsers that do not automatically upscale (currently safari is the only one) ... https://github.com/jondavidjohn/hidpi-canvas-polyfill

Comment: I've been developing a JS framework that solves problem of canvas blur with DIV mosaic. I produces a clearer and sharper image at some cost in terms of mem/cpu http://js2dx.com

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The canvas element runs independent from the device or monitor's pixel ratio.

On the iPad 3+, this ratio is 2.  This essentially means that your 1000px width canvas would now need to fill 2000px to match it's stated width on the iPad display.  Fortunately for us, this is done automatically by the browser.  On the other hand, this is also the reason why you see less definition on images and canvas elements that were made to directly fit their visible area.  Because your canvas only knows how to fill 1000px but is asked to draw to 2000px, the browser must now intelligently fill in the blanks between pixels to display the element at its proper size.

I would highly recommend you read [this article](https://web.dev/canvas-hidipi/) from [Web.dev](https://web.dev/) which explains in more detail how to create high definition elements.

tl;dr?
Here is an example (based on the above tut) that I use in my own projects to spit out a canvas with the proper resolution:

```
var PIXEL_RATIO = (function () {
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

    return dpr / bsr;
})();


createHiDPICanvas = function(w, h, ratio) {
    if (!ratio) { ratio = PIXEL_RATIO; }
    var can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = w * ratio;
    can.height = h * ratio;
    can.style.width = w + "px";
    can.style.height = h + "px";
    can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
    return can;
}

//Create canvas with the device resolution.
var myCanvas = createHiDPICanvas(500, 250);

//Create canvas with a custom resolution.
var myCustomCanvas = createHiDPICanvas(500, 200, 4);
```

Comment: Thought it would be worth mentioning that my createHiDPI() method is somewhat poorly named.  DPI is a term for print only and PPI is a more proper acronym as monitors display images using pixels as opposed to dots.

Comment: Note that this ratio can actually change during the lifetime of the page. For example, if I drag a Chrome window from an older "standard" res external monitor to a built-in retina screen of a macbook the code will calculate a different ratio. Just an FYI if you plan to cache this value. (external was ratio 1, retina screen 2 in case you're curious)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. But how about image assets? Do we need to supply every canvas image at double resolution and scale it down manually?

Comment: @Piet Binnenbocht - It depends on your image asset.  If your image isn't saved at a higher resolution, no amount of scaling on the canvas context will help.  It is also worth noting that when drawing a HiDPI canvas to another HiDPI canvas using the drawImage method, I had to multiply certain arguments by the calculated pixel ratio to keep the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: This polyfill fixes most basic canvas operations with HiDPI browsers that do not automatically upscale (currently safari is the only one) ... https://github.com/jondavidjohn/hidpi-canvas-polyfill

Comment: More trivia: Windows Phone 8's IE always reports 1 for window.devicePixelRatio (and backing pixels call doesn't work). Looks awful at 1, yet a ratio of 2 looks good. For now my ratio calculations anyways return at least a 2 (crappy workaround, but my target platforms are modern phones which nearly all seem to have high DPI screens). Tested on HTC 8X and Lumia 1020.

Comment: @Aardvark: it also seems that msBackingStorePixelRatio is always undefined. Asked a new question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483296/html5-msbackingstorepixelratio-doesnt-exist-are-there-workarounds-for-high-de

Comment: backingStorePixelRatio is no longer defined in Chrome, see [this discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277205#c9). The thread states that its value was always 1.

Comment: This is a great solution! However, it falls down if the pixel density changes for any reason. For example, the pixel density will change if the user changes the browser's zoom settings. This can cause accessibility problems with a blurry canvas. My solution was to add an onresize listener to the window, and in this instance recalculate the pixel ratio, and if appropriate, recreate the canvas. This gives nice sharp text even if browser zoom is used.

Comment: If you're using WebGL, you may  have to set the `transform` css style instead of getting the 2d context of the canvas. Just change the last line in the `createHiDPICanvas` function to can.style.transform = ` scale(${1/ratio}) `;

Comment: backingStorePixelRatio is depreciated and undefined in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my MacBook. Only document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d").webkitBackingStorePixelRatio returns a number in Safari and that number is 1. 
So it seems defining PIXEL_RATIO as equal to `window.devicePixelRatio || 1`will give the same result.

Comment: Note that if you were drawing in a canvas and then used the above code to change the canvas from blurry to crisp, you'll have to update all its drawing commands as well because the old point `(x, y)` is now located at `(x * PIXEL_RATIO, y * PIXEL_RATIO)`.

Comment: THanks! How to get it with Node.js server where there is no window objetc?

Comment: @BallpointBen I don't believe your comment is accurate. The call to `.setTransform()` should automatically adjust the position of all drawing to match the scale of the canvas.

Comment: @MyNameIsKo - Most people don't know this, but the 'D' in DPI stands for "Device independent element."  And first the 'P' in PPI stands for "Posh silliness."

Answer (score 33):

**Solved!**

I decided to see what changing the *width* and *height* attributes I set in `javascript` to see how that affected the canvas size -- and it didn't. It changes the resolution.

To get the result I wanted, I also had to set the `canvas.style.width` attribute, which changes the physical size of the `canvas`:

```
canvas.width=1000;//horizontal resolution (?) - increase for better looking text
canvas.height=500;//vertical resolution (?) - increase for better looking text
canvas.style.width=width;//actual width of canvas
canvas.style.height=height;//actual height of canvas
```

Comment: I disagree.  Changing the style.width/height attributes is exactly how you create a HiDPI canvas.

Comment: In your answer, you set canvas.width to 1000 and canvas.style.width to half at 500.  This works but only for a device with a pixel ratio of 2.  For anything below that, like your desktop monitor, the canvas is now drawing to unnecessary pixels.  For higher ratios you are now right back where you started with a blurry, low res asset/element.  Another issue that Philipp seemed to be alluding to is that everything you draw to your context must now be drawn to your doubled width/height even though it is being displayed at half that value.  The fix to this is to set your canvas' context to double.

Comment: There is `window.devicePixelRatio`, and it's well implemented in most modern browsers.

Comment: No window objetc in Node.js if I  need to generate a canvas in the server :/

Answer (score 32):

While @MyNameIsKo's answer still works, it is a little outdated now in 2020, and can be improved:

```js
function createHiPPICanvas(width, height) {
    const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.width = width * ratio;
    canvas.height = height * ratio;
    canvas.style.width = width + "px";
    canvas.style.height = height + "px";
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);

    return canvas;
}
```

In general, we make the following improvements:

- We remove the `backingStorePixelRatio` references, as these aren't really implemented in any browser in any important way (in fact, only Safari returns something other than `undefined`, and this version still works perfectly in Safari);
- We replace all of that ratio code with `window.devicePixelRatio`, [which has fantastic support](https://caniuse.com/?search=window.devicePixelRatio)
- This also means that we declare one less global property --- hooray!!
- We can also remove the `|| 1` fallback on `window.devicePixelRatio`, as it is pointless: all browsers that don't support this property don't support `.setTransform` or `.scale` either, so this function won't work on them, fallback or not;
- We can replace `.setTransform` by `.scale`, as passing in a width and height is a little more intuitive than passing in a transformation matrix.
- The function has been renamed from `createHiDPICanvas` to `createHiPPICanvas`. As @MyNameIsKo themselves mention in their answer's comments, DPI (Dots per Inch) is printing terminology (as printers make up images out of tiny dots of coloured ink). While similar, monitors display images using pixels, and as such PPI (Pixels per Inch) is a better acronym for our use case.

---

One large benefit of these simplifications is that this answer can now be used in TypeScript without `// @ts-ignore` (as TS doesn't have types for `backingStorePixelRatio`).

Comment: thanks for this update. however, does this address the concern raised by @spenceryue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027313/144088?

Answer (score 14):

Try this one line of CSS on your canvas:
`image-rendering: pixelated`

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering):

> When scaling the image up, the nearest-neighbor algorithm must be used, so that the image appears to be composed of large pixels.

Thus it prevents anti-aliasing entirely.

Comment: Oh my goodness - had I known about this 5 years ago, I could have prevented so many headaches!! It works flawlessly and extremely well; it can be easily applied to the canvas element which is useful for existing web apps which suffer from the problem!!

Answer (score 8):

I resize canvas element via css to take whole width of parent element. I noticed that width and height of my element is not scaled. I was looking for best way to set size which should be.

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

This simple way your canvas will be set perfectly, no matter what screen you will use.

Answer (score 8):

This 100% solved it for me:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

(it is close to Adam Mańkowski's solution).

Answer (score 8):

I noticed a detail not mentioned in the other answers. **The canvas resolution truncates to integer values.**

The default canvas resolution dimensions are `canvas.width: 300` and `canvas.height: 150`.

On my screen, `window.devicePixelRatio: 1.75`.

So when I set `canvas.height = 1.75 * 150` the value is truncated from the desired `262.5` down to `262`.

A solution is to choose CSS layout dimensions for a given `window.devicePixelRatio` such that truncation will not occur on scaling the resolution.

For example, I could use `width: 300px` and `height: 152px` which would yield whole numbers when multiplied by `1.75`.

**Edit**: Another solution is to take advantage of the fact CSS pixels can be fractional to counteract the truncation of scaling canvas pixels.

Below is a demo using this strategy.

**Edit**: Here is the OP's fiddle updated to use this strategy: http://jsfiddle.net/65maD/83/.

```js
main();

// Rerun on window resize.
window.addEventListener('resize', main);


function main() {
  // Prepare canvas with properly scaled dimensions.
  scaleCanvas();

  // Test scaling calculations by rendering some text.
  testRender();
}


function scaleCanvas() {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

  // Get desired dimensions for canvas from container.
  let {width, height} = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Get pixel ratio.
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
  
  // (Optional) Report the dpr.
  document.querySelector('#dpr').innerHTML = dpr.toFixed(4);

  // Size the canvas a bit bigger than desired.
  // Use exaggeration = 0 in real code.
  const exaggeration = 20;
  width = Math.ceil (width * dpr + exaggeration);
  height = Math.ceil (height * dpr + exaggeration);

  // Set the canvas resolution dimensions (integer values).
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  /*-----------------------------------------------------------
                         - KEY STEP -
   Set the canvas layout dimensions with respect to the canvas
   resolution dimensions. (Not necessarily integer values!)
   -----------------------------------------------------------*/
  canvas.style.width = `${width / dpr}px`;
  canvas.style.height = `${height / dpr}px`;

  // Adjust canvas coordinates to use CSS pixel coordinates.
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
}


function testRender() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  // fontBaseline is the location of the baseline of the serif font
  // written as a fraction of line-height and calculated from the top
  // of the line downwards. (Measured by trial and error.)
  const fontBaseline = 0.83;
  
  // Start at the top of the box.
  let baseline = 0;

  // 50px font text
  ctx.font = `50px serif`;
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, baseline + fontBaseline * 50);
  baseline += 50;

  // 25px font text
  ctx.font = `25px serif`;
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, baseline + fontBaseline * 25);
  baseline += 25;

  // 12.5px font text
  ctx.font = `12.5px serif`;
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, baseline + fontBaseline * 12.5);
}
```

```css
/* HTML is red */

#container
{
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  /* Setting a border will mess up scaling calculations. */
  
  /* Hide canvas overflow (if any) in real code. */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

/* Canvas is green */ 

#canvas
{
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.8);
  animation: 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate both comparison;
}

/* animate to compare HTML and Canvas renderings */

@keyframes comparison
{
  33% {opacity:1; transform: translate(0,0);}
  100% {opacity:.7; transform: translate(7.5%,15%);}
}

/* hover to pause */

#canvas:hover, #container:hover > #canvas
{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* click to translate Canvas by (1px, 1px) */

#canvas:active
{
  transform: translate(1px,1px) !important;
  animation: none;
}

/* HTML text */

.text
{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.text:nth-child(1)
{
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.text:nth-child(2)
{
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.text:nth-child(3)
{
  top: 75px;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  line-height: 12.5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Make the desired dimensions strange to guarantee truncation. -->
<div id="container" style="width: 313.235px; height: 157.122px">
  <!-- Render text in HTML. -->
  <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  
  <!-- Render text in Canvas. -->
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- Interaction instructions. -->
<p>Hover to pause the animation.<br>
Click to translate the green box by (1px, 1px).</p>

<!-- Color key. -->
<p><em style="color:red">red</em> = HTML rendered<br>
<em style="color:green">green</em> = Canvas rendered</p>

<!-- Report pixel ratio. -->
<p>Device pixel ratio: <code id="dpr"></code>
<em>(physical pixels per CSS pixel)</em></p>

<!-- Info. -->
<p>Zoom your browser to re-run the scaling calculations.
(<code>Ctrl+</code> or <code>Ctrl-</code>)</p>
```

Comment: Great ! How could I get this focused text if I generate the canvas image with Node.js server? (no window object in Node) THanks

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` is used in every answer here. It's client-dependent, and even for a single client, it's _zoom_-dependent (can change at any time). The client would need to supply this information to whatever canvas you're using (whether it be in a web worker or a server).

Comment: For me the ratio is 1.25 and for instance width=500 is fine but can't fix it with width=501

Comment: Do you mean this implementation doesn't work if the "visible CSS width is 501px"? If the visible width (`container.style.width`) is `501px` and `devicePixelRatio` is `1.25`, then the logical canvas width (`canvas.width`) should be `Math.ceil(501 * 1.25) = 627` and the visible canvas width (`canvas.style.width`) should be `627 / 1.25 = 501.6` (`px`).

Answer (score 3):

I slightly adapted the [MyNameIsKo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666143/3045952) code under [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) (SVG to Canvas js library). I was confused for a while and spend some time for this. Hope this help someone.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart"><canvas></canvas><svg>Your SVG here</svg></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {

var PIXEL_RATIO = (function () {
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

    return dpr / bsr;
})();

setHiDPICanvas = function(canvas, w, h, ratio) {
    if (!ratio) { ratio = PIXEL_RATIO; }
    var can = canvas;
    can.width = w * ratio;
    can.height = h * ratio;
    can.style.width = w + "px";
    can.style.height = h + "px";
    can.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
}

var svg = document.querySelector('#chart svg'),
    canvas = document.querySelector('#chart canvas');

var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
var w = svgSize.width, h = svgSize.height;
setHiDPICanvas(canvas, w, h);

var svgString = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawSvg(svgString, 0, 0, w, h);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you working in reactjs, I adapted MyNameIsKo's answer and it works great.  Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react'

export default class CanvasComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.calcRatio = this.calcRatio.bind(this);
    } 

    // Use componentDidMount to draw on the canvas
    componentDidMount() {  
        this.updateChart();
    }

    calcRatio() {
        let ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
          ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
        return dpr / bsr;
    }

    // Draw on the canvas
    updateChart() {

        // Adjust resolution
        const ratio = this.calcRatio();
        this.canvas.width = this.props.width * ratio;
        this.canvas.height = this.props.height * ratio;
        this.canvas.style.width = this.props.width + "px";
        this.canvas.style.height = this.props.height + "px";
        this.canvas.getContext("2d").setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
        const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

       // now use ctx to draw on the canvas
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref={el=>this.canvas=el} width={this.props.width} height {this.props.height}/>
        )
    }
}
```

In this example, I pass in the width and height of the canvas as props.

Answer (score 1):

Before high-resolution screens existed, each CSS pixel was supposed to represent exactly one physical pixel on a given screen.

However, with the advent of high-resolution screens, this relationship no longer held. High-resolution screens have smaller pixels, forcing browsers to scale up their contents so that they are appropriately sized.

The blur your experience is a result of this scaling, since your browser tries imperfectly to "fill in the gaps" as you scale up.

So... how can you fix the issue of scaling-induced blur?

**The key is to produce a higher-resolution image while leaving canvas size fixed.**

In other words, and more explicitly, you should increase the logical resolution of the **inside** of your canvas, so that the **logical resolution** within your canvas matches the **physical resolution** of that region of your screen... without changing the **external** size of the canvas's box in your CSS layout.

Now, I'll show you exactly how to do this in JavaScript.

Preliminary facts:

- the scaling factor your browser uses to scale its contents is
  `window.devicePixelRatio`. (For example, on my MacBook Pro, it's 2,
  meaning there are 2 physical pixels for each CSS pixel.)
- `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` can be used to set the logical
  resolution **within** the canvas, while `canvas.style.width` and
  `canvas.style.height` can be used to set the **external** size of the
  canvas's box, in CSS pixels, within its CSS layout. These are distinct, and it is because they are distinct that we can change the logical resolution within the canvas without changing the size of the canvas!

Here is the code:

```
// Size the canvas box in CSS pixels.
canvas.style.height = "300px";
canvas.style.width = "300px";

function setUpHiResCanvas(canvas) {
  // Get the device pixel ratio, falling back to 1.
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  // Get the size of the canvas in CSS pixels.
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Scale the resolution of the drawing surface
  // (without affecting the physical size of the canvas window).
  canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
  canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Scale all drawing operations,
  // to account for the resolution scaling.
  ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
  return ctx;
}
```

**Voila!** The above was what solved the problem of blurry canvas text caused by a high-resolution screen for me.

For more details and a differently-worded explanation, see https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-resize-a-canvas-on-high-resolution-screens-e96324a0617 .

Answer (score 0):

For me, only a combination of different 'pixel perfect' techniques helped to archive the results:

1. Get and scale with a pixel ratio as @MyNameIsKo suggested.

   **pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio/ctx.backingStorePixelRatio**
2. Scale the canvas on the resize (avoid canvas default stretch scaling).
3. multiple the lineWidth with pixelRatio to find proper 'real' pixel line thickness:

   **context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;**
4. Check whether the thickness of the line is odd or even. add half of the pixelRatio to the line position for the odd thickness values.

   **x = x + pixelRatio/2;**

The odd line will be placed in the middle of the pixel. The line above is used to move it a little bit.

```js
function getPixelRatio(context) {
  dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
}


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pixelRatio = getPixelRatio(context);
var initialWidth = canvas.clientWidth * pixelRatio;
var initialHeight = canvas.clientHeight * pixelRatio;


window.addEventListener('resize', function(args) {
  rescale();
  redraw();
}, false);

function rescale() {
  var width = initialWidth * pixelRatio;
  var height = initialHeight * pixelRatio;
  if (width != context.canvas.width)
    context.canvas.width = width;
  if (height != context.canvas.height)
    context.canvas.height = height;

  context.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
}

function pixelPerfectLine(x) {

  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  thickness = 1;
  // Multiple your stroke thickness  by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;

  context.strokeStyle = "Black";
  context.moveTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x), getSharpPixel(thickness, 0));
  context.lineTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x), getSharpPixel(thickness, 200));
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function pixelPerfectRectangle(x, y, w, h, thickness, useDash) {
  context.save();
  // Pixel perfect rectange:
  context.beginPath();

  // Multiple your stroke thickness by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;
  context.strokeStyle = "Red";
  if (useDash) {
    context.setLineDash([4]);
  }
  // use sharp x,y and integer w,h!
  context.strokeRect(
    getSharpPixel(thickness, x),
    getSharpPixel(thickness, y),
    Math.floor(w),
    Math.floor(h));
  context.restore();
}

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  pixelPerfectLine(50);
  pixelPerfectLine(120);
  pixelPerfectLine(122);
  pixelPerfectLine(130);
  pixelPerfectLine(132);
  pixelPerfectRectangle();
  pixelPerfectRectangle(10, 11, 200.3, 443.2, 1, false);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(41, 42, 150.3, 443.2, 1, true);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(102, 100, 150.3, 243.2, 2, true);
}

function getSharpPixel(thickness, pos) {

  if (thickness % 2 == 0) {
    return pos;
  }
  return pos + pixelRatio / 2;

}

rescale();
redraw();
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Resize event is not fired in the snipped so you can try the file on the [github](https://github.com/ievgennaida/js-animation-timeline-control/blob/master/demo/pixel-perfect-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not only image but text had bad quality.
The simplest cross browser working solution for retina/non-retina displays was to render image twice as big as intended and scale canvas context like this guy suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921030/4837965

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked directly for me (while others didn't):

```
    const myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    const originalHeight = myCanvas.height;
    const originalWidth = myCanvas.width;
    render();
    function render() {
      let dimensions = getObjectFitSize(
        true,
        myCanvas.clientWidth,
        myCanvas.clientHeight,
        myCanvas.width,
        myCanvas.height
      );
      const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
      myCanvas.width = dimensions.width * dpr;
      myCanvas.height = dimensions.height * dpr;

      let ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
      let ratio = Math.min(
        myCanvas.clientWidth / originalWidth,
        myCanvas.clientHeight / originalHeight
      );
      ctx.scale(ratio * dpr, ratio * dpr); //adjust this!
    }

    // adapted from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/intrinsic-scale
    function getObjectFitSize(
      contains /* true = contain, false = cover */,
      containerWidth,
      containerHeight,
      width,
      height
    ) {
      var doRatio = width / height;
      var cRatio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
      var targetWidth = 0;
      var targetHeight = 0;
      var test = contains ? doRatio > cRatio : doRatio < cRatio;

      if (test) {
        targetWidth = containerWidth;
        targetHeight = targetWidth / doRatio;
      } else {
        targetHeight = containerHeight;
        targetWidth = targetHeight * doRatio;
      }

      return {
        width: targetWidth,
        height: targetHeight,
        x: (containerWidth - targetWidth) / 10,
        y: (containerHeight - targetHeight) / 10
      };
    }
```

The implementation was adapted from [this](https://medium.com/wdstack/fixing-html5-2d-canvas-blur-8ebe27db07da) Medium post.