# How to set HTML5 canvas size to match display size in device pixels

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, pixel

**Is it possible to set the size of the bitmap in an HTML5 canvas so that it exactly matches the display size in device pixels, ie the number of physical pixels used to display the canvas, even when `window.devicePixelRatio` is not an integer?**

There is a good description of how to resize the canvas on [webglfundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html) but it does not properly handle non-integer `devicePixelRatio`s. My understanding so far:

- The display size of the canvas is set in CSS with, eg, `canvas {width: 200px;}`.
- The underlying bitmap size is set with, eg, `<canvas width="100"/>` in HTML or `canvas.width = 100` in JS.
- The bitmap will be stretched to fit the CSS size (how is affected by `object-fit` and `object-position`).
- We can set bitmap size to be equal to some expression involving `canvas.clientWidth`.
- `canvas.clientWidth` is an integer and its unit are CSS pixels and is the calculated width of the content (plus padding). I don't know if the browsers actually draw the content into a whole number of CSS pixels or a whole number of device pixels.

So webglfundamentals suggests something like

```
canvas.width = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth * window.devicePixelRatio);
```

but if `window.devicePixelRatio` is a fraction, this sometimes doesn't work (2 pixel wide lines drawn on integer coordinates are fuzzy). My 1920x1080 screen has `devicePixelRatio` of 1.5 by default, and page zoom can affects this, so lots of reasons why `devicePixelRatio` is not an integer as a rule. What can we do?

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` will never be an integer, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio): A double-precision floating-point value

Comment: @JackBashford I think that he meant a natural number and not a fraction

Comment: So he means he wants to round it @NielsNet?

Comment: Can you not just set the canvas width and height to 100% using CSS?

Comment: Jonathan, no that only affects the display size without any regard to the bitmap size.

Comment: The following helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244519/766476

Comment: The webglfundamentals artical that you've linked mentions a way to get canvas's size in actual device pixels using ReziseObserver and devicePixelContentBoxSize. Though it is not yet supported in Safari

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I hope I can help a bit any other wanderer coming to this.

There is a way to make a "canvas pixel" match "device pixel" as close to a 1:1 ratio as possible, at least from my experience while making a Canvas WebGL based game engine, even with non-integer `devicePixelRatio` values.

First, there are 3 things we need to understand:

- **CSS Size**: Refers to the actual Canvas DOM element size in CSS pixel (`px`) units.
- **Canvas Size**: Logical size of the canvas, as set using the element properties (i.e. `canvasElem.width = 100;`), this affects your render space.
- **Device Pixel Ratio**: Value obtained from `window` which effectively describes the ratio between a `physical pixel` and a `CSS pixel`.

### Brief Example

Let's say you have a `devicePixelRatio` of `2.625`, and your mobile device reports a screen/window size of `411 x 487` -a weird size- you might say, but that is in CSS pixel units, if we multiply those by the `devicePixelRatio` we get a size of `1078 x 1278` which tells us that most likely the device screen is actually a `1080 x 1280` screen, as originally advertised by your favorite phone manufacturer.

### Now, to size stuff...

Say we want a canvas filling the whole screen. Set your **CSS Size** match the screen size (or any box size you want).

```js
canvas.style.width = '411px';
canvas.style.height = '487px';
```

Now set the **Canvas Size** to the same but scaled-up by `devicePixelRatio`:

```js
canvas.width = 411 * window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height = 487 * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Now you can render your images.

When the browser calculates the layouts, it will have to scale-down your canvas to make it fit in its DOM rectangle area, the down-scale factor is `cssSize / canvasSize` yielding a down-scale factor of `1 / devicePixelRatio`.

And then when the browser needs to render the layout to physical screen, it will scale it up by `devicePixelRatio`, thus leaving a total scaling of `1.0`.

### TL;DR

Supersampling. Scale up your canvas logical size by `devicePixelRatio` while keeping your CSS size at whatever size you need, and let the browser do the rest.

**NOTE:** If your rendering expects the canvas to be of certain size, and this "scaling up" messes up your layout and/or calculations, use the canvas `setTransform` method to scale down your "logical units" by `1.0 / devicePixelRatio`, no quality is loss at all.

Answer (score 0):

1px is a logical length unit in CSS/DOM realm. Dot.

So I don't think that you will find reliable method for getting physical pixels. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680629/getting-the-physical-screen-dimensions-dpi-pixel-density-in-chrome-on-androi).

That's why in [Sciter](https://sciter.com) I've made `px` units to represent always **physical pixels** of the device. And introduced `dip` units that are logical pixels - 1/96 of inch measured by the ruler on device surface (so 1dip ~ 1px of W3C CSS).

I simply do not understand how to do serious UI development without the ability to define objects in device pixels.

Comment: Thanks for replying as a UI authority and for the link to the well-seen question. I'll still leave the question open for a bit.

Comment: It was Apple who, in their infinite wisdom -- practically to sell their first iPhone -- who came up with the rather idiotic additional "level of indirection" or complexity, if you will, that is now known by a great term of "logical pixel". And we've all been pulling our hair out ever since.