# Canvas fillRect an fillText is blurry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using canvas and when ever I use fillRect or fillText the text and shapes are blurry. Is there any way to fix this I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You are using CSS to set the size of your canvas... Don't do that. There are `width` and `height` attributes and properties on your canvas. Use these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the font size and gradient width properties for it?
for example -

```
ctx.font="20px Text";
ctx.fillText("Hello!",10,50);

ctx.font="30px Verdana";

var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
```

What parameters are you passing to these properties?
And check out the following link -

[How do I fix blurry text in my HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661339/how-do-i-fix-blurry-text-in-my-html5-canvas)

Hope it Helps.