# Font on canvas is stretched out and squished

Tags: javascript, canvas

When I'm rendering text onto the canvas, it seems like it's being stretched out and squished together. How can I fix this?
(Images are zoomed in to show the differences in font. Both are at 900% zoom)

What I want:
[image]

What I'm getting:
[image]

My code:

```js
            this.ctx.textAlign = "left";
            this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            this.ctx.font = "10px Verdana";
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            this.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(204, 204, 204, 1)";
            this.ctx.fillText(text, startX, startY);
```

Comment: Is your canvas affected by transforms? Maybe [antialiasing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-imagesmoothingenabled)?

Comment: There are no transformations other than clip. Changing imageSmoothing didn't do anything.

Comment: Have you setted width/height of the canvas in percentage, with CSS/style attribute?

Comment: I'm setting the width/height to innerWidth and innerHeight (pixels) via javascript
```this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    });
```

Comment: Try to fix width and height (like 600x400) and see if it is an aspect ratio problem. Take also a look at this [blurry html text on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661339/how-do-i-fix-blurry-text-in-my-html5-canvas) or either this [canvas text rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066166/canvas-text-rendering-blurry)