# HTML Blurry Canvas Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I use jcrop to provide users with a friendly way of uploading their images via ajax. Obviously these images have some constraint like width and height which is where jcrop comes into play. So for the sake of brevity what im doing is as follows:

input file select via javascript file api loads the image into a img tag. Jcrop works with this image tag and renders the result onto a html canvas.

Now this is the dodgy part. The canvas image is always blurry...

for arguments sake the canvas is set to 400x200 which is the crop size.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the canvas width and height is set via CSS it results in a blurry image result. TO get around this I had to set the width and height via html attributes. Now I have a wonderful cropping solution that can save images via AJAX. Crisp and Clear:)

```
<canvas id="preview" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helps but I cant understand how it happens.? can you explain this?(for knowledge purpose only)

Comment: Hi Pulah, tbh I have no idea why the css styles result in it being blurry whole the inline parameters don't. I might look into this when I have some spare time on my hands.

Comment: Thanks Ben I will also look into this & if I get an answer I will add it. & Btw its **Pulah** . :)

Comment: Anyone have idea about what this happen? @BenPretorius you make my day, thank you

Comment: @Sebastian, glad I could help someone out there:)

Comment: @BenPretorius I'm afraid this is only part of the solution. Accordings to this [excellent article on Canvas and pixelDeviceRatio](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi) your solution would only be crisp on standard-resolution displays, or on HD-displays in Safari, not Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the Info Andy! I will have a look when I got a gap.

Answer (score 5):

According to [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-canvas-width), if width or height attribute is missing, then the default value must be used instead, which is 300 for width and 150 for height. And these two attributes will determine the canvas's width and height, while the css properties merely determine the size of the box in which it will be shown.

> The canvas element has two attributes to control the size of the element's bitmap: width and height. These attributes, when specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers. The rules for parsing non-negative integers must be used to obtain their numeric values. If an attribute is missing, or if parsing its value returns an error, then the default value must be used instead. The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150.
>
> The intrinsic dimensions of the canvas element when it represents embedded content are equal to the dimensions of the element's bitmap.
>
> The user agent must use a square pixel density consisting of one pixel of image data per coordinate space unit for the bitmaps of a canvas and its rendering contexts.
>
> **A canvas element can be sized arbitrarily by a style sheet, its bitmap is then subject to the 'object-fit' CSS property.**

You can refer to the following post for more details:
[Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Answer (score 2):

This is really just an extension of the answer above.  I too encountered the problem of CANVAS images resized using Javascript/CSS becoming fuzzy and blurry, because my application first used HTML to create a few DIVs, one of which held a CANVAS control, then the ONLOAD event called a Javascript routine to get the screen size, optimise the sizes and positions of all the DIVs and the CANVAS accordingly, and finally draw on the CANVAS.  I did it that way as I wanted the CANVAS to always be as big possible for whatever device it was viewed on.

My solution is to use Javascript to dynamically draw the CANVAS control too, i.e. for the DIV that contains the CANVAS simply include...

```
var CanvasWidth=screen.availWidth-30;
var CanvasHeight=screen.availHeight-190;
//The 30 and 90 above are arbitrary figures to allow for other DIVS on the page
var o=window.document.getElementById("IdOfDivContainingCanvas");
o.innerHTML="<canvas id='myCanvas' width='"+CanvasWidth+"' height='+CanvasHeight+'></canvas>";
```

...so that the size of the CANVAS is effectively dynamic; Created with it's size specified using HTML attributes, just before executing the Javascript statements that actually draw on the CANVAS.