# Why is rendering blurred in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I'm very new to WebGL. I tried copying and pasting code from a WebGL tutorial https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html to render randomly sized and randomly colored rectangles, but found that the rectangles were very blurry in my browser (Firefox 67.0.4).

I've pasted the screenshot below. Because the image below is much smaller, the blurriness isn't as apparent as when viewed in my browser, but you can still see that it's blurry.

[image: Screenshot of random rectangles WebGL render]

Does anyone know why it's coming out blurry in my browser, and how to fix?

Below I've re-pasted in its entirety the code for the WebGL program:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
   // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

   // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
   vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

   // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
   vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

   gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>

<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script>
//MAIN JAVASCRIPT CODE FOLLOWS HERE

"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // look up uniform locations
  var resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  var colorUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Clear the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Turn on the attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // draw 50 random rectangles in random colors
  for (var ii = 0; ii < 50; ++ii) {
    // Setup a random rectangle
    // This will write to positionBuffer because
    // its the last thing we bound on the ARRAY_BUFFER
    // bind point
    setRectangle(
        gl, randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300));

    // Set a random color.
    gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);

    // Draw the rectangle.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 6;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
  }
}

// Returns a random integer from 0 to range - 1.
function randomInt(range) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a rectangle.
function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();

</script>

<style>
@import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Blurry Canvas Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854336/html-blurry-canvas-images): your CSS is stretching your 300x150 canvas to the entire viewport.

Comment: Thank you, @AuxTaco, but where do you see my canvas is 300x150? I set canvas to 100%, and I still get the blur

Comment: The canvas size is defined in the HTML: `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`. Without `width` and `height` attributes set, it [defaults to 300x150](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Attributes). See also [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with “width” / “height” properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is is because you put the style section at the end. Things get executed in order so first the script executes. At that time there is no style so the canvas is the default 300x150. The script draws. Then the `<style>` section comes and tells the browser to display that 300x150 texture the full size of the window. Move the style section before the script or ideally to the top.

Still the sample only renders one time. If you resize the page it does not re-render so even if you move the `<style>` above the `<script>` if the window starts small and you resize the window larger you'll still get blur.

To handle resizing you'd need to render the rectangles again. To draw the same rectangles you'd need to save the positions, sizes, and colors used. It would be up to you to decide if they should stay the same size relative to the window or not, the same aspect or not.

You might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html) useful.

The code below picks 50 random rectangles and colors

```
  // pick 50 random rectangles and their colors
  const rectangles = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < 50; ++ii) {
    rectangles.push({
      rect: [randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300)],
      color: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1],
    });
  }
```

It then draws the previously picked rectangles in a render function

```
function render() {
     ...

    for (const rectangle of rectangles) {
      // This will write to positionBuffer because
      // its the last thing we bound on the ARRAY_BUFFER
      // bind point
      setRectangle(
          gl, ...rectangle.rect);

      // Set the color.
      gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, ...rectangle.color);

      // Draw the rectangle.
      var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
      var offset = 0;
      var count = 6;
      gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }
}
```

finally it calls `render` when the page resizes

```
window.addEventListener('resize', render);
```

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

  // look up uniform locations
  var resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  var colorUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // pick 50 random rectangles and their colors
  const rectangles = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < 50; ++ii) {
    rectangles.push({
      rect: [randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300), randomInt(300)],
      color: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1],
    });
  }

  function render() { 
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // set the resolution
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    for (const rectangle of rectangles) {
      // This will write to positionBuffer because
      // its the last thing we bound on the ARRAY_BUFFER
      // bind point
      setRectangle(
          gl, ...rectangle.rect);

      // Set the color.
      gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, ...rectangle.color);

      // Draw the rectangle.
      var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
      var offset = 0;
      var count = 6;
      gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }
  }
  render();
  window.addEventListener('resize', render);
}

// Returns a random integer from 0 to range - 1.
function randomInt(range) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a rectangle.
function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
  var x1 = x;
  var x2 = x + width;
  var y1 = y;
  var y2 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     x1, y1,
     x2, y1,
     x1, y2,
     x1, y2,
     x2, y1,
     x2, y2,
  ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
   // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

   // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
   vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

   // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
   vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

   gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this code handle the sizing to make sure the canvas is propery sized to the viewport?     `webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);`

Comment: It does, one time only (the code in your question, not the code in this answer). The code in your question the page is only draw one time. After that it's never drawn again so if you start with a small window and resize to a large window it will get blurry unless you refresh the page. The example in the answer re-renderers every time page window is resized.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, but please note I never resized my window. It came out blurry on the first render, without any re-sizing.

Comment: Please note, @gman, I upvoted your answer because it's very helpful, but I temporarily unchecked the answer because I still can't figure out why I'm getting the blur. I set canvas sizes to 100% and maximized browser before rendering, and never resized browser, but am still getting blur.

Comment: sorry, fixed the answer