# How can I set Html5 Canvas FillStyle with dynamic pattern and color

Tags: html5-canvas

I would like to set dynamically a color and pattern to a shape using html5 canvas. The pattern is a .png image. When I research the topic I found that you can not mix fillStyle = pattern and fillStyle = color The canvas shape will get only one of them. I would like to have a color in the background and image pattern in the forward dynamically. That is possible?

any idea will be appreciate.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just draw the circular path twice:

- First time with the solid lime fill
- Second time with the pattern

[image]

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
setCanvas(canvas, ctx, 300, 300);

var img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKmeL.png";

function start() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150, 150, 130, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  ctx.fill();

  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696631/canvas-drawings-like-lines-are-blurry/59143499#59143499
function setCanvas(canvas, ctx, w, h) {
  canvas.style.width = w + "px";
  canvas.style.height = h + "px";
  const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.width = w * scale;
  canvas.height = h * scale;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale );
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

[Golden Star](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Golden_star.svg)