# canvas blurry and distorted on chrome windows 10

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome

## The Problem

So I've been developing a bar chart for my website using an array of samples between the values of `0` and `140`. The graph itself looks fine running on my *MacBook* in *Chrome* (*MacOS High Sierra* **10.13.3** and *Chrome* **67.0.3396.87**) - however, on my *Windows* **10** device, the graph looks incredibly blurry in *Chrome* (strangely enough it still works in *IE*, *Edge* and *Firefox* just as it does on my *MacBook*).

This is how it looks on my *MacBook*:

[image: MacBook Canvas]

And this is how it looks on my *PC* (in *Chrome*):

[image: PC Canvas]

---

## My Code

```
var wave = {
    samples: null,
    draw: function(canvas, color){
        /* 
        *   @param {node} canvas - a canvas element
        *   @param {string} color - a hexadecimal, rgb or rgba value
        */
        var x = 0,
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            samples = this.samples;

        // iterate through all the samples
        for(var i = 0; i < samples.length; i++){
            ctx.fillStyle = color;

            // draw a 'bar' that is 2 pixels wide, 
            // and make each bar height relative to 
            // the canvas (60px) and sample heights
            // ie: 140 would become 60px in height
            ctx.fillRect(
                x + (x * 2), // left
                60 - (samples[i] * (60 / 140)), // top
                2, // width
                samples[i] * (60 / 40) // height
            );
            ctx.fill();

            x++;
        }
    },
    init: function(layer, samples){
        /* 
        *   @param {node} layer - a dom node (the bar chart canvas)
        *   @param {array} samples - an array of samples ranging from 0 to 140, eg: [0, 40, 45, 50, 140]
        */
        this.samples = samples;
        this.draw(layer, "#919191");
    }
}
```

How it is implemented (**example**):

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="600" height="60"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cvs"),
        samples = [21, 46, 83, 72, 127]; // etc..
    wave.init(canvas, samples);
</script>
```

---

I haven't come across a problem like this on the internet so far, and it has been bugging me for a while now. So anyone that could find me a solution, it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**: I have noticed that if I set a set the `transform` property on the canvas to `scale(0.91)` it looks perfectly fine (.. other than being the wrong size haha)

Comment: It seems like the aliasing bugs on chrome, sometime I just enlarge the page then everything comes fine again...

Comment: Have you checked if your browser has been zoomed in? i.e. not at 100% zoom.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if you're using CSS to style the canvas, that can cause blurriness ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854465/6243352))